# Obtaining a reference to frmMain

Tags: c#, .net

I am programming in C# with .NET.  I used the form designer to create a form.  I added a serial port object to the form which I made public.  Visual Studio auto generated a class called `frmMain : form`.  I decided to write a class dedicated to the serial port interface which I called `Serial_Comm_Handler`.  I want to access the serial port object (`serialPortCOM`) within my `Serial_Comm_Handler` class.  Additionally I would want to call member functions later.  Everything is in the same namespace.

I am confused on how to access the object reference to the frmMain object.  I am trying to follow how the Visual Studio auto generated code instantiates the formMain object.  I followed it back to `Program Class`, `Main` function, both are *static*.  There is a call to `Application.Run(new frmMain)` here.

I am guessing that this is where the reference to the form is created. I was hoping to create references to both of my classes here in this area which are public so that they can access each other.  Is this the right place?  I tried a few things but because the class and function are static then it doesn't seem to want to let me do this.  I'd love to get some advice if this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, your handler classes shouldn't directly call methods or access properties on the UI.

If Serial_Comm_Handler needs the serial port object, your form (which owns this object) should be the one to instantiate the handler class and pass the serial port object to it.

If the handler needs to notify the form of a change, it should do so by using events. Note that if this is WPF (I'm assuming its not), then it should notify the view model, which would then notify the UI via PropertyChanged.

If you REALLY need access to the form class, it depends on where you instantiate the handler. If you do it in the Program class (definitely not recommended), then you could refactor the new statement to assign to a reference before calling Application.Run, then instantiate your handler with the reference. If the form is constructing the handler, just pass it "this" to give it the reference.

Also not recommended, because it involves statics, but you could have some static property on the form class that exposes the serial port object.

Again, you really shouldn't need a reference to the form in your handler. Your handler deals with a serial port it is given and raises events. It shouldn't care where the serial port come from or what the UI is.

Comment: I took your advice and added the instance of the `Serial_Comm_Handler` class into my frmMain object.